# PHP gd Instalation on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, gd

i just try to instal php gd library in my ubuntu server with this command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

but always return

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-gd'
```

maybe someone, any idea? i was try any command but return same

btw im using php 7.4 in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has reached its (regular) End-Of-Life. PHP7.4 has reached its End-Of-Life. Maybe it's time to upgrade

Comment: Have you tried adding the apt-repository of ondrej/php? ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php```

Then do a update and try installing it again

Comment: @mhaendler solved thanks!